# How to make a reusable two-way pipe?

Tags: angular

From what I understand there is no way in Angular to use pipes on a two-way databinding. Essentially, what I would like to do is:

```
<input name="humidity" [(ngModel)]="humidity | percent">
```

> Coming from a background of programming .NET WPF I am used to be able
>   to have data transformed in both way (from model to UI, and from UI to
>   model) using [value
>   converters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

If I instead change the code to:

```
<input name="humidity" [ngModel]="humidity | percent" (ngModelChange)="humidityChanged($event)" >
```

...I'm able to manually in code make the backward "pipe transformation" before storing the data to the model. Please see [my Plunker for full code sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/FH7NAjiYqzuzeyaNt4sz/) using this approach.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better approach in the current or upcoming
   version of Angular?
2. If I want the backward-pipe-transformation to be reusable (in the
   same manner as the percent pipe is reusable), is it a good way to
   create a PercentComponent containing an `<input>` along with the
   needed code?

Comment: Pipe is one-way, that's the purpose. Why should it be a two-way thing? You need to process the value when it's changed (e.g. in humidityChanged), it will automatically update view, no ` | percent` is necessary. That's how bindings work. That's why we have a model in the first place, it's used as a single source of truth.

Comment: @estus, thank you for your feedback. I am having a hard time understanding the rationale why a pipe must be one-way.
I am lacking support for two-way since I am used to have it from WPF. In WPF pipes (a.k.a value converters) where two-way so in the pipe you had the function _transform(…)_ but **also** the function _transformBack(…)_.

I see a benefit in that you can place all the transformation logic in a single place. This pipe can then be easily reused.

Are you suggesting me to not use the percent pipe at all and instead make all data transformations in the model object?

Comment: Yes, that's what should be done here. I guess they didn't call them value converters intentionally. Instead, pipes are same things as filters from AngularJS, with some benefits.

Comment: Great @estus, then I understand. I will mark your post as the answer if there are no better alternatives.
I still believe ”value converters” would be valuable in Angular. In the suggested solution, extending the model with a _humidityPercentage_ property is no good way to encapsulate the transformation logic and make it reusable.
At the same time, I sense you are telling me that two-way data binding is not the preferred “Angular-way”. Instead, most focus is on one-way data-binding and in a manual but controlled way handle the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular do not support data converters (i.e. two-way pipes) and there is no indication of any future support.

You can create a custom reusable class containing the transformation logic (`transform(..)` and `transformBack(..)`). Still, you will need to extend you model with for instance a new property everywhere where you want to use it.

Angular pipes are direct counterparts of AngularJS filters and suppose to transform view data. They are one-way, as a part of one-way data flow that Angular propagates.

If a value is supposed to be changed both in view and a model, it should be changed in model only, then it will be automatically updated in view. This consists with a role of a model as single source of truth.

`humidity | percent` is supposed to be used when a value should be shown with a percent in view but remain a number in model.

For instance, this is different in Aurelia which shares a lot of ideas with Angular but has *value converters* instead of pipes, they (as the name suggests) are capable of converting values in both directions.

Comment: The model represents data from a server in which humidity is a fraction (0,34).
I want the humidity to be displayed and editable in an input box as a percentage (34%).
In this case, I interpret you that I should not use pipes.   

As value converters do not exists within Angular, I must write the needed data transformation within my model.
Please see [my new Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/OMnxEgavcR3DLEw8evkF/) if it have understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's quite accurate way to do this. I usually prefer reactive forms and form controls to ngModel because they give a better control over data flow.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar case - an input field with two-way binding to a model. I want to define a list of options in it in the form of a string array, but I want the user to see just comma separated values instead of parsed JSON array.

I managed to do this by applying the pipe to the input binding like this:

```
[model]="boundObject.value | stringArrayToCSV"
```

and for whenever the user changes input value, I get the changes using

```
(modelChange)="onValueChanged($event, boundObject)"
```

onValueChanged function looks like this (simplified):

```typescript
onValueChanged(value: string, boundObject: any) {
  try {
    const array = value.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
    boundObject.value = JSON.stringify(array);
  } catch (e) {
    boundObject.value = value;
  }
}
```